# How i can get object from my database class in AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, sql, android-asynctask

i need to get object of database class in my `AsyncTask` class. The main problem is,i can't refer to "`getApplicationContext();`" so i can't use methods from this class properly. I need mine object of database class here, because i want to populate spinner with data from database. How i should make it? I can't extend `AsyncTask` for 2 classes. I'll post some code below for methods that i want to use.

MainActivity

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
    switch (id){
        case PLEASE_WAIT:
            ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            dialog.setTitle("Looking for database with exercises");
            dialog.setMessage("Please wait ...");
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
    }
    return null;
}
```

AsyncTaskDB

```
public class AsyncTaskDB extends  AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
Activity activity;

public AsyncTaskDB(Activity activity){
    this.activity = activity;
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    activity.showDialog(MainActivity.PLEASE_WAIT);

}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    databaseHelper db = new databaseHelper();
    activity.removeDialog(MainActivity.PLEASE_WAIT);

}
}
```

database

```
public boolean shouldPopulate(){
    return getCalfData().isEmpty() && getLegsData().isEmpty() && getBackData().isEmpty() && getAbsData().isEmpty() && getBicepsData().isEmpty() && getTricepsData().isEmpty() && getChestData().isEmpty() && getShouldersData().isEmpty();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand correctly what is the problem exactly, so if this is wrong answer, please clarify your question and post your code of DataBase.class and Activity.class where you invoke AsyncTaskDB.

Why you can't do in `AsyncTask` like that?

```
DataBase database = new DataBase();
```